# Send push/email notification to specific user AWS SNS

Tags: ios, swift, aws-sdk, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

How can I send specific notification to a particular user using AWS SNS service. I am able to configure the application and code at iOS part to receive the sns notification but through SNS console.

How can I send and receive the notifcation from iOS only for specific users? I am not able to find any helpful demonstration on it.